# strip punctuation with regex - python

Tags: python, regex

I need to use regex to strip punctuation at the *start* and *end* of a word. It seems like regex would be the best option for this. I don't want punctuation removed from words like 'you're', which is why I'm not using .replace().

Comment: For those coming here looking for a way to distinguish between Unicode alphanumeric characters and everything else, while using Python 3.x, you can just use \w and \W in your regular expression. This just helped me code the Control-Shift-Left/Right functionality in a Tkinter text widget (to skip past all the stuff like punctuation before a word). I found your post before I found that solution. So, I figure it may help someone in a similar boat.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You don't need regular expression to do this task. Use [`str.strip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.strip) with [`string.punctuation`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string#string.punctuation):

```
>>> import string
>>> string.punctuation
'!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
>>> '!Hello.'.strip(string.punctuation)
'Hello'

>>> ' '.join(word.strip(string.punctuation) for word in "Hello, world. I'm a boy, you're a girl.".split())
"Hello world I'm a boy you're a girl"
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what would be the regex method for this?

Comment: `re.sub('\S+', lambda m: re.sub('^\W+|\W+$', '', m.group()), '...')`. NOTE: You need to replace `\W` to be exact because it will exclude `_` (if you treat `_` as a punctuation character).  DEMO: http://ideone.com/Ti44Bw

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!  
By the way, is this equivalent to yours - `re.sub('\S+', lambda m: re.match(r'^\W*(.*\w)\W*$', m.group()).group(1), text)`?   
If yes, then which one of them is faster (or otherwise better)?  
[Demo](http://ideone.com/EDan4X)

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi, using `timeit`, you can measure them. http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html

Comment: Okay, but are they equivalent?

Comment: Downvoted because the OP specifically asked for a regex solution

Comment: @ArthurKhazbs, regular expression solution is in the comment. :)

Comment: Upvoted for the mention of `string.punctuation`, I didn't realize that existed!

Comment: string.punctuation contains ASCII punctuation chars, but not non-ASCII Unicode punctuation chars, of which there are many.  This page:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33787354/strip-special-characters-and-punctuation-from-a-unicode-string
shows how to do it while including all Unicode chars (although it does not address the issue of apostrophes in words like "don't" or Tzeltal's "awo'tan").

Answer (score 4):

I think this function will be helpful and concise in removing punctuation:

```
import re
def remove_punct(text):
    new_words = []
    for word in text:
        w = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',word) #remove everything except words and space
        w = re.sub(r'_','',w) #how to remove underscore as well
        new_words.append(w)
    return new_words
```

Comment: Note, you can simplify your conditions further with `w = re.sub(r'([^\w\s]|_)','',word)`

Answer (score 4):

If you persist in using Regex, I recommend this solution:

```
import re
import string
p = re.compile("[" + re.escape(string.punctuation) + "]")
print(p.sub("", "\"hello world!\", he's told me."))
### hello world hes told me
```

Note also that you can pass your own punctuation marks:

```
my_punct = ['!', '"', '#', '$', '%', '&', "'", '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '.',
           '/', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', '[', '\\', ']', '^', '_', 
           '`', '{', '|', '}', '~', '»', '«', '“', '”']

punct_pattern = re.compile("[" + re.escape("".join(my_punct)) + "]")
re.sub(punct_pattern, "", "I've been vaccinated against *covid-19*!") # the "-" symbol should remain
### Ive been vaccinated against covid-19
```

Comment: This doesn't comply with OP request of maintaining punctuation for words i.e. "he's" and "I've"

Answer (score -4):

You can remove punctuation from a text file or a particular string  file using  regular expression as follows -

```
new_data=[]
with open('/home/rahul/align.txt','r') as f:
    f1 = f.read()
    f2 = f1.split()



    all_words = f2 
    punctuations = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~''' 
    # You can add and remove punctuations as per your choice 
    #removing stop words in hungarian text and  english text and 
    #display the unpunctuated string
    # To remove from a string, replace new_data with new_str 
    # new_str = "My name$#@ is . rahul -~"

    for word in all_words: 
        if word not in punctuations:
           new_data.append(word)

    print (new_data)
```

P.S. - Do the identation properly as per required.
Hope this helps!!