# Strip special characters and punctuation from a unicode string

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7, unicode

I'm trying to remove the punctuation from a unicode string, which may contain non-ascii letters. I tried using the `regex` module:

```
import regex
text = u"<Üäik>"
regex.sub(ur"\p{P}+", "", text)
```

However, I've noticed that the characters `<` and `>` don't get removed. Does anyone know why and is there any other way to strip punctuation from unicode strings?

EDIT: Another approach I've tried out is doing:

```
import string
text = text.encode("utf8").translate(None, string.punctuation).decode("utf8")
```

but I would like to avoid converting the text from unicode to string and backwards.

Comment: You should define what punctuation is. Especially in unicode this might be very many characters and character combinations depending on your language.

Comment: You don't need to convert to UTF-8 at tall to use `unicode.translate()`. Use `text.translate(dict.fromkeys(ord(c) for c in string.punctuation))`.

Comment: And `\p{P}` does not include `<` as `>`; those are not classified as punctuation. They are [Math Symbol (Sm)](https://codepoints.net/search?gc=Sm) chodepoints.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Ah! but `string.punctuation`

Comment: However, `string.punctuation` contains them. That seems a bit inconsistent.

Comment: @ivanab: `string.punctuation` is determined by a [different standard](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_4.html) from Unicode. The two don't agree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<` and `>` are classified as [Math Symbols (Sm)](https://codepoints.net/search?gc=Sm), not Punctuation (P). You can match either:

```
regex.sub('[\p{P}\p{Sm}]+', '', text)
```

The `unicode.translate()` method exists too and takes a dictionary mapping integer numbers (codepoints) to either other integer codepoints, a unicode character, or `None`; `None` removes that codepoint. Map `string.punctuation` to codepoints with `ord()`:

```
text.translate(dict.fromkeys(ord(c) for c in string.punctuation))
```

That only removes only the limited number of *ASCII* punctuation characters.

Demo:

```
>>> import regex
>>> text = u"<Üäik>"
>>> print regex.sub('[\p{P}\p{Sm}]+', '', text)
Üäik
>>> import string
>>> print text.translate(dict.fromkeys(ord(c) for c in string.punctuation))
Üäik
```

If `string.punctuation` is not enough, then you can generate a complete `str.translate()` mapping for all `P` and `Sm` codepoints by iterating from 0 to `sys.maxunicode`, then test those values against [`unicodedata.category()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.category):

```
>>> import sys, unicodedata
>>> toremove = dict.fromkeys(i for i in range(0, sys.maxunicode + 1) if unicodedata.category(chr(i)).startswith(('P', 'Sm')))
>>> print text.translate(toremove)
Üäik
```

(For Python 3, replace `unicode` with `str`, and `print ...` with `print(...))`.

Comment: I am getting error `_regex_core.error: unknown property at position 12` when run `regex.sub('[\p{P}\p{Ms}]+', '', text)`

Comment: @SIslam: my mistake, I got the abbreviation for the class wrong. I've since corrected it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try `string` module

```
import string,re
text = u"<Üäik>"
out = re.sub('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation), '', text)
print out
print type(out)
```

Prints-

```
Üäik
<type 'unicode'>
```

Answer (score 0):

`\p{P}` matches punctuation characters.

Those punctuation characters are

```
! ' # S % & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ / ] ^ _ { | } ~
```

`<` and `>` are not punctuation characters. So they won't be removed.

Try this instead

```
re.sub('[\p{L}<>]+',"",text)
```