# Error when using string.punctuation to remove punctuation for a string

Tags: python, nltk, punctuation

Quick question:

I'm using `string` and `nltk.stopwords` to strip a block of text of all its punctuation and stopwords as part of data pre-processing before feeding it into some natural language processing algorithms.

I've tested each component separately on a couple blocks of raw text because I'm still getting used to this process, and it seemed fine.

```
    def text_process(text):
        """
        Takes in string of text, and does following operations: 
        1. Removes punctuation. 
        2. Removes stopwords. 
        3. Returns a list of cleaned "tokenized" text.
        """
        nopunc = [char for char in text.lower() if char not in string.punctuation]

        nopunc = ''.join(nopunc)

        return [word for word in nopunc.split() if word not in 
               stopwords.words('english')]
```

However, when I apply this function to the text column of my dataframe – it's text from a bunch of Pitchfork reviews – I can see that the punctuation isn't actually being removed, although the stopwords are.

Unprocessed:

```
    pitchfork['content'].head(5)

0    “Trip-hop” eventually became a ’90s punchline,...
1    Eight years, five albums, and two EPs in, the ...
2    Minneapolis’ Uranium Club seem to revel in bei...
3    Minneapolis’ Uranium Club seem to revel in bei...
4    Kleenex began with a crash. It transpired one ...
Name: content, dtype: object
```

Processed:

```
    pitchfork['content'].head(5).apply(text_process)


0    [“triphop”, eventually, became, ’90s, punchlin...
1    [eight, years, five, albums, two, eps, new, yo...
2    [minneapolis’, uranium, club, seem, revel, agg...
3    [minneapolis’, uranium, club, seem, revel, agg...
4    [kleenex, began, crash, it, transpired, one, n...
Name: content, dtype: object
```

Any thoughts on what's going wrong here? I've looked through the documentation, and I haven't seen anyone who's struggling with this problem in the exact same manner, so I'd love some insight on how to tackle this. Thanks so much!

Comment: Please don't post images of code or data. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Got it! I'll change that right now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Without seeing your actual data, it's hard to say. But one thing to check is that the punctuation marks that aren't being removed are actually in the list of ascii `string.punctuation` and not other characters. For example, `'?' in '!"\'#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~'` is True, but hwat about your quotation marks? Based on your update: `" != ”`

Comment: `string.punctuation` just contains ASCII punctuation. The characters you're seeing are non-ASCII curly quotes.

Comment: Yeah! It's quotation marks – both single and double – that aren't being removed. Are they in a different list? I've used this one before and not had issues, so that hadn't actually occurred to me.

Comment: The problem is that the list of all Unicode punctuation is enormous, they haven't tried to enumerate all of them.

Comment: Hmm. I think the only forms of punctuation that aren't being removed here are single and double quotes – do you have a suggestion as to how I might remove just those?

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, by the way!

Comment: Maybe check the category of a character - https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.category - see if it starts with a `'P'`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strip special characters and punctuation from a unicode string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33787354/strip-special-characters-and-punctuation-from-a-unicode-string) .. If you end up making a table as shown in the accepted answer you can use it like: `pitchfork['content'] = pitchfork['content'].str.translate(toremove)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that utf-8 has different encodings for left and right quotation marks (single and double), rather than just the regular quotation mark that is included in `string.punctuation`.

I would do something like

```
punctuation = [ c for c in string.punctuation ] + [u'\u201c',u'\u201d',u'\u2018',u'\u2019']

nopunc = [ char for char in text.decode('utf-8').lower() if char not in punctuation ]
```

this adds the utf-8 values for the non-ascii quotation marks to a list called `punctuation`, and then decodes the text to `utf-8`, and replaces those values.

note: this is python2, if you're using python3, the formatting of the utf values will likely be slightly different